# Do I(my gateway) have a public ip?

Tags: router, ip-address

when I search for "my public ip", google returns `103.12.15.1` (changed). My router's WAN side IP is `10.5.184.23` and its gateway is `10.5.184.12`, not a public ip. When I traceroute to `8.8.8.8` from my router, this is what I get:

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
 1  10.5.184.12 (10.5.184.12)  4.327 ms  6.880 ms  2.860 ms
 2  103.12.15.1 (103.12.15.1)  6.807 ms  4.739 ms  3.904 ms
 3  103.12.15.201 (103.12.15.201)  6.369 ms  6.849 ms  15.123 ms
 4  150.107.206.250 (150.107.206.250)  10.626 ms  15.744 ms  13.094 ms
 .
 .
```

`10.5.184.12` is my ISP's AP to which I connect via PPPoE.
So, what can I make from this observations.

Comment: You'll learn more about your network from doing a traceroute to your own public IP address.

Answer (score 2):

You have already asserted that your WAN IP address is 10.5.184.23 - which, by definition (RFC1918) means you do not have a public IP.

In order to get onto the wider Internet at some point in your providers network address translation must be taking place - presumably on the router which is connected to yours, and "103.12.15.1" would be the real world IP address that NAT device is providing - but it is clearly not connected to your device.

It is possible that your provider is doing a 1:1 mapping between the real-world IP address and your router - I've seen that kind of behaviour before, but that would not be on your router.

Comment: I didn't think about 1:1 mapping. Perhaps that is what they are doing, but is there any benefit of doing that? Otherwise, giving two suscribers a single public ip doesn't make sense, does it? Say, I do something nasty assuming that public ip via secure connection, the ISP would have no way of being sure it's me, or am i missing something?

Comment: One possible benefit would be saving of IP space.   If you have a point 2 point link, you require 4 IP addresses  - Network, Gateway, Local IP and Gateway IP.   If you use RFC1918 space and map that onto real addresses you can get 253 client addresses without tricks out of it (+gateway).

Comment: If there is a 1:1 mapping your ISP could be sure it was you - even if there isn't, if they are competent they will have logs mapping your RFC1918 address to the real address at the given time.   (This assumes you are using a real ISP, not some pseudo ISP who just wires up apartments or office complexes) and connects it to a real ISP - And indeed that is the only place I've seen this IP address mapping in my part of the world.

Answer (score 2):

It tells us that your ISP implements a private network up to your demarc, and does its routing to the public Internet upstream from you.

The question is, how do they map your private IP to the public one you see on Google. There are several possibilities:

- Static 1-1: Each internal address has exactly one unique external address, which never changes. External users can establish connections to any port on the end system (though firewalls will likely be in play). you could probably even register a standard DNS name for the address (though the ISP may not like that).
- Dynamic 1-1: Each internal address has exactly one unique external, which is dynamically assigned, and will change periodically. External users can establish connections to any port on the end system (though firewalls will likely be in play). For DNS you would need a Dynamic DNS Provider and hardware capable of working with that provider.
- Carrier NAT: The ISP has a pool of public IPs, and uses NAT to map each individual connection to a public IP and port. No one could connect to you at all, except within a connection you solicited from inside the ISP network.

In either of the 1-1 methods, you could be said to have a public IP. In the NAT scenario however, no, you definitely do not.

The easiest way to tell would be to check the IP periodically, to determine whether it changes. Then you can try setting up a simple server of some kind (perhaps a httpd) on a weird port and see if you can sucessfully set up port forwarding and test the port with a service like http://canyouseeme.org.

Comment: I think we can rule out Carrier NAT because, like idiots, they are using 10.x.x.x - Carrier NAT should not use RFC1918 space, rather using 100.64.0.0/10 - These guys are probably small time clueless players - although I think your post is otherwise spot on - I think they are using Consumer grade NAT to do what should be done using Carrier Grade NAT.

Comment: The public IP remains the same, I've checked it once in a while for like 2 months.  As +davidgo suggested they are probably pseudo ISP and they do have very small subscriber base.

Comment: I tried setting up server on some port and forwarding the port from my router, but I can't see them from outside.

Comment: then in that case there is likely a firewall or stateful NAT wall between you and the Internet at large. If you really need a public IP, you will probably have to purchase one from them, if they have the capability.